# How to make fonts look similar in urxvt and gnome-based applications

Tags: linux, fonts, xorg, urxvt

I have recently switched from gnome-terminal to urxvt, which I like much better. However, I like the way the fonts are rendered in gnome-based applications better. Here is a screenshot comparing urxvt running vim on the left and gvim on the right. Running vim on gnome-terminal also gives the appearence of the right side.

[image]

Urxvt seems to have a more "antialiased" look, but I think it's a bit too much. The Gnome version gives a better contrast, which is nicer for my eyes.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any Xresource settings? Like `URxvt.font:          xft:Monospace:size=8` and `Xft.antialias: true`

Comment: I have `URxvt.font: xft:Andale Mono-9:antialias=false:autohint=false`. The antialias does not change anything, and it is also not the issue, since I already tried disbaling it in `/etc/fonts/config.d`. Without antialias it's very ugly, simply unusable.

Comment: Yes, but the font size does look different. Try changing it to the same one gvim/gnome uses?

Comment: They are both Andale Mono 9. I think it lloks bigger because it is rendered differently, with more space between the letters

Comment: From searching around it looks like we're the only ones that want to achieve this. The closest thing I found relevant to this goal is [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841872/why-the-font-dejavu-sans-mono-looks-different-in-gvim-and-emacs) which may point to an inherently different font rendering mechanism, since I think urxvt also uses libxft. I managed to get the fonts as close as possible but urxvt was still blurring the fonts too much, which was definitely noticeable in characters such as asterisks.